# Drupal 8 Admin toolbar keeps disappearing

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

When I create my new Drupal site on my localhost, I have my admin toolbar for maybe a day. The next time I fire it up locally, the admin toolbar is gone and I can't manage my site at all.

Attached is how it looks after creating the new site and running install.php. Stays like this for a day and then that tool bar is completely removed and I can't do anything.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Wish I could provide more info upfront but I'm new to Drupal and not entirely sure what is missing.

Comment: and you are sure that you are logged in?

Comment: go to webrooturl/user and log in?

Comment: Check the browser console for javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure `admin_toolbar_tools` module is enabled.

If module state is fine, then it might be some module breaks menu tree for admin tools.

In my case it was `social_admin_menu` module from open open social package.

There is service called `social_admin_menu.administrator_menu_tree_manipulators` with class     `Drupal\social_admin_menu\Menu\SocialAdminMenuAdministratorMenuLinkTreeManipulators`, and the class has `checkAccess()` method that alters access to some menu items in tree.

The issue was in logic check `if ($this->account->id() !== 1)`, since `id()` method returns string there.

Searching by use of `'admin_toolbar_tools'` in custom modules or contrib modules other than `admin_toolbar_tools` could help you detect the issue, most probably there will be use of root item `'admin_toolbar_tools'` for this menu somewhere.